# How can I add a texture to a joint in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

Maybe I could do it with the anchor points, but I don't really understand how I should do that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm building needs to have a `SKSpriteNode` with a texture for the joint, then add it as a child of one of the conjoining nodes, such that it covers the area the `SKPhysicsJoint` is operating on. 
Anytime I rotate the joint the texture rotates with it. I got the idea from action figures with `hidden joints`, basically, you're just putting something over the mechanical joint, in order to make for more pleasing aesthetics.

I don't know if this will work for you, but you could also define a texture using the centerRect of an existing texture and then define the part you want to paint on the joint node. This is more work than I wanted to put in, depending on your artwork assets this may be a good way to get around having another image in your bundle.
 I'm the artist as well as the programmer, so its faster for me to just create a joint image and add another node over the upper and lower nodes in the joint.

Answer (score 0):

Joints can't have a texture. You can estimate or for some joints calculate where the connection point is by using the two connected body's positions and then put a sprite there (and continue to update the sprite's position).

Comment: Yeah, but I just don't get it how i can calculate the rotation! Do you have any idea? Thanks